# Wants to get the cookies and then login into site, CURL PHP

Tags: php, curl, cookies

Stuck in getting the cookies is there any way to get the cookie of ASP-based website I tried many ways to auto-login into the website with CURL I used almost everything can anyone please guide me on how I take the cookies from the header and then log in to it with a cookie, I guess in this cookie is creating on runtime when I someone press the submit form button it generating cookie that time, so can any one have an idea how I take that cookie and login it? i am attaching the code which i write maybe i doing some mistake in sending the header or i am calling the wrong url. thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$url = "https://lorabet2.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 'authority: lorabet2.com',
 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
 )); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo($result);
if($result != "")
{
  $postData = array(
   'login' => $user,
  'password' => $pass,
  'submit' => 'submit', # From the "Submit" button
  );
 var_dump ($postData);
  $ch = curl_init();
 $url1 = "https://lorabet2.com/api/user/login";
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'method: POST',
   'path: /api/user/login',
   'scheme: https',
   'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
 )); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo ($result);
curl_close($ch);
}
else {
    echo "empty";
}
?>
```

Comment: Try looking at the option `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` - it allows you to specify a file to store cookies in and reuse on subsequent requests

Comment: I tried cookie jar too, but cookie is not generated in cookie text file.